# Is it possible to set up an ejabberd cluster in master-slave mode where data is not being replicated?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, master-slave

I am trying to setup a very simple cluster of 2 `ejabberd` nodes. However, while trying to go through the official [ejabberd documentation](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/clustering/) and using the `join_cluster` argument that comes along with the `ejabberdctl` script, I always end up with a multi-master cluster where both the `mnesia` databases have replicated data.

Is it possible to set up a ejabberd cluster in `master-slave` mode? And if yes, then what I am I missing?

Comment: It is possible. You can configure Mnesia on all the slaves to use RAM-only table copies, such that only the master stores data on disk. I'm not sure if you can use `ejabberdctl` to do that, or if you need to set it up manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, a slave get the data replicated but would simply not be active. The slave needs the data to be able to take over the task of the master at some point.
It seems to means that the core of the setup you describe is not about disabling replication but about not sending traffic to the slave, no ?

In that case, this is just a matter of configuring your load balancing mechanism to route the traffic accordingly to your preference..

Comment: Nope. I already have a load balancer in place that routes the traffic to both the nodes based on the `leastconn` algorithm with both ejabberd instances getting some traffic which I have verified through the ejabberd logs.

Comment: Then, what is your question about ? What is the point in not replicating the data ? Anyway, you can manually set all Mnesia tables as remote on slave. The read and writes will happen from the slave to the master, at the expense of increased network traffic and latency. To do that, you need to avoid creating a local copy of the table when you set your cluster.

Comment: I was under the impression that the `ejabberd` cluster can be configured in a way where the data could be partitioned between the deployed `ejabebrd` nodes so that if 1 node gets the request and can't fulfill it, then that request gets forwarded to the other node internally. Don't you think keeping the databases in sync is a big overhead for `ejabberd` overall? Wouldn't this pose a problem when there are a large number of requests to be fulfilled?

Comment: No, this is not a problem and is much better for many reasons: Fault-tolerance and lower network traffic. For huge site anyway, you need a very special tuned architecture for the special use case at hand. However, the standard setting is doing wonders for most of the deployments.